# Can I reject an accepted job offer couple of days before the starting date?

Tags: job-offer

I have already accepted a job offer. I have already finished background check, filled out W-4 and I-9 forms. The starting date is only 5 days away. Today, I got a better offer. If I accept the second job offer, should I tell the new company that I accepted an offer before? Will they be able to find out by conducting a background check?

Answer (score 3):

> If I accept the second job offer, should I tell the new company that I
>   accepted an offer before?

No, assuming you don't have to delay your start at the second company due to obligations at the first.

> Will they be able to find out by conducting a background check?

Probably not. It's not clear how much they would care anyway.

Comment: If I accept the new offer, I will most likely have a gap between the starting date and the date I quit my current job. Is that a big issue?

Comment: Are you in some industry where having a week gap between jobs is some big problem?  Literally no one cares about this except the company you accepted and then bailed on, who will be sad for a week and then forget about it.

Comment: You should mention this is still quite unprofessional, and could give the OP a reputation.

Comment: Just wanted to highlight "due to obligations at the first" - double check there isn't a resignation period already in place if you have signed the contracts etc. Usually the first few months are probationary and no notice is required though

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join the second company, I would suggest you write an email to the HR of the first company politely stating that you won't be able to join them due to so and so reason.
And I don't think the second company will come to know anything in the background check.

Thank you.